# Using variables from cmd commands

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I'm trying to make a batch program that fetches variables from base CMD commands.
For example:

```
c:\Users> ipconfig
.....
IPv4 Address ....... 123.456.7.89
.....
```

Say I wanted to make a batch program that prints only the IP address on the screen such as:

```
@echo off
echo (IP Address Variable Here)
pause;
```

What would I need to do?

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I wanted to make a batch program that prints only the IP address on the screen

Use the following batch file.

**GetIPAddress.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem throw away everything except the IPv4 address line 
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /i "ipv4"`) do (
  rem we have for example "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.78"
  rem split on : and get 2nd token
  for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
    rem we have " 192.168.42.78"
    set _ip=%%b
    rem strip leading space
    set _ip=!_ip:~1!
    )
  )
echo %_ip%
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The value you want is saved in `_ip`

**Example usage and output:**

```
F:\test>ipconfig | findstr /i "ipv4"
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.78

F:\test>GetIPAddress
192.168.42.78
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [ipconfig](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html) - Configure IP (Internet Protocol configuration)
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).